# Plot a 3D plot for pandas data using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to make a figure similar to [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/polys3d_demo.html). and the code is like

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
def cc(arg):
    return mcolors.to_rgba(arg, alpha=0.6)
xs = np.arange(0, data.shape[0])
verts = []
zs = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
for idx, value in enumerate(zs):
    ys = data[data.columns[idx]]
    ys[0], ys[-1] = 0, 0
    verts.append(list(zip(xs, ys)))
poly = PolyCollection(verts, facecolors=[cc('r'), cc('g'), cc('b'),
                                         cc('y'), cc('g'), cc('b')])
poly.set_alpha(0.7)
ax.add_collection3d(poly, zs=zs, zdir='y')

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

data here is a dataframe, and we want to plot for each line. But actually, I can't get any content with the code above. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

Since all other codes of yours are the same as the example's, the error must come from your coding tools (e.g., cterm or jupyter notebook) or your data.
I wonder if you're using ssh or jupyter without interaction backend.

Comment: It seems this is not the problem. and I can run the original code correctly.

Comment: So the error must come from the data. Try to check the shape of data?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can run the original code correctly but not the code you provided, check that you have imported all the right libraries before running this code.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

---

If I run your code importing only `pyplot`, then I get a window without any content, which seems to be the problem you are having.